# Stuck on vs caught on vs snagged on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Let's say I walk by a door and my shirt gets **"trapped"** by the door.

Did it get **snagged on** the door?

Did it get **caught on** the door?

Did it get **stuck on** the door?

How do these 3 phrasal verbs **differentiate** from one another?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "stuck on" if there were some sticky substance (like chewing gum or glue) either on your shirt or the door that caused them to stick together.

I might use "stuck *in*" if your shirt was actually "trapped" by the door closing on it.

"Snag" is defined as ["a rough sharp or jagged projecting part: PROTUBERANCE"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snag) - so if there was something protruding from the door (like a knob or hook) that your shirt ended up on I would use "snagged".

"Catch" means ["to get entangled"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch) (see definition 2g) - if your shirt got tangled up as a result of something on the door then "caught on" would be appropriate.

I think "caught in" could be used like "stuck in" or "trapped". "...in the door" generally means "between the door and the doorframe". But (just to be thorough with all three verbs and both prepositions) I don't think "snagged in" is something people would say.